# Can this DFA be converted to a regular expression?

Tags: automata, regular-languages, regular-expressions

I want to make the regular expression of this language but I can't: I tried but the regular expression didn't match some strings that it should. Is it even possible?

[image]

Comment: _Every_ DFA/NFA can be converted to a regular expression and there are standard techniques for doing this. See the linked question.

Comment: i make a regular expression but every possible strings are not generated  by them and i consult to a teacher i also could not

Comment: Have you tried following (one of) the answers in the link given by @DavidRicherby? If yes, can you give a detailed account how much you have done and where you are stuck? (By the way, welcome to [cs.SE]!) In fact, image is not very welcomed here since it makes your question impossible to search and difficult to edit or copy. You are expected to transcribe text and mathematics (by [LaTeX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) usually).

Comment: @Apass.Jack The information in the image is inherently pictorial. I can't see any other reasonable way of presenting it. In particular, something like the transition table of the automaton would be much less intuitive and still not searchable.

Answer (score 2):

*Every* DFA can be converted to a regular expression, so you must have made a mistake when you converted. The conversion is quite fiddly, so making a mistake with a nine-state automaton is easy to do, unfortunately.

It might help if you split the automaton in two: if the automaton accepts, it either reads an $a$ and then accepts using only states $2,4,6,\omega$ or it reads a $b$ and then accepts using only states $3,5,7,\omega$. So the regular expression must be something of the form $aR_{\{2,4,6,\omega\}}+bR_{\{3,5,7,\omega\}}$, where $R_S$ is the regular expression for the automaton that just has the states in $S$. Now, you just have to convert two nearly identical four-state automata, which should be easier to do correctly.

Comment: it seems you are accepting the existence of final and start to be granted. i am confused to see how you can make regular expression without declaring the final and start state of automata

Comment: @rajendra I'm assuming that, in the diagram in the question, the state marked with "-" is the start state (note that it has no incoming transitions) and the states marked with "+" are accepting. I've never seen that convention before but, as you say, the question doesn't make a whole lot of sense, otherwise.

Comment: a(a+b)b((a+b)*+b(a+b)a((a+b)a)*  i had make this RE but it cant generate all possible strings

Comment: @Salma That's almost correct. The problem is that states 4, 5, 6 and 7 are all accepting but your RE looks like it only has 4 and 5 accepting.

Comment: how i can correct it?

Comment: By being more careful so you don't make mistakes. I've shown you all the skills you need to solve this problem; it's up to you, now.